# How do you get JSON data using $.getJSON with Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, drupal

I'm new to Node.js. I already have a frontend javascript script that uses an API and gets weather data like so:

```
function getTextWeatherUsingStation(theStation){

 theURL = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';

    //    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            $.getJSON(theURL,function(data){
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data)
```

I read that you can't just use a library as is. I converted it over to a Node.js friendly file by wrapping it in

```
module.exports = {
```

and altering the function to:

```
getTextWeatherUsingStation: function(theStation){
```

It was having problem with promise so I just commented it out as you can see. 
I was getting errors on the $.getJSON  line and figured it was because I hadn't included jQuery so I used npm to install that.

I'm still getting this and can't figure out why:

```
....\drupal-8.4.5\stationFunctionsNode.js:34
            $.getJSON(theURL,function(data){
            ^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.getTextWeatherUsingStation (C:\Users\edwin.brown\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-8.4.5\stationFunctionsNode.js:34:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edwin.brown\Sites\devdesktop\drupal-8.4.5\nodeTestWData.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Node.js ???? The site seems to be a Drupal site. What version of Drupal? If Drupal 8, have you included jquery on the page (Drupal 8 does not load jquery on pages by default)

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is jQuery's function for front to make `http` requests.

You are on backend now. So things will be little different here. This is not how you make requests from backend instead should consider using one of the  native modules to make `http` requests which is `http` module and you use it like

```
 http.request(Options, function(res) { ...
```

Or if you want to use something like `getJson` here is [`get-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-json) library that you can use like

```
getJSON('URL', function(error, response){..
```

Ofcourse you'll have to install it first with `npm install get-json`

then use in your project like   `var getJSON = require('get-json')`

Comment: I used        request(url, (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

Comment: Will these comment responses not allow formatting? and limit number of characters? Kind of hard to respond to you this way